# How to find the particular region in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to bind the event (click) to the particular region (red shadow box) specified in the attached image using javascript or Jquery

[image]

How to bind event to the region..?

Please help me to resolve the issue..

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: Can you please explain more? What kind of event?

Comment: Do you have such element? Have you done the skewing with css3 rules?

Comment: You would need to interrogate the event to find the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties. You would then need to write the logic to determine if this falls within the shape you're trying to detect. This is by no means a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

An old, but reliable technique would be to use `<map>` tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

```html
<p>Click on the sun:</p>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKoAr.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" onclick="alert('Hello Sun!')">
</map>
```

**But**, you wanted it for a `div`. You could use an overlaying, transparent image on top of your `div`. You'd lose the ability to interact with the `div` itself though, if you care about that.

Otherwise, you'd just have to use JavaScript and handle the event using the clicked coordinates found via `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties. You'll probably have to deal with some cross browser issues depending on the browser's you'd like to support.